# store content of a textblock in a gridview into a variable

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-store-apps, textblock

i am developing a windows store app. I have a gridview control which has a textblock named "fileName". I have programmatically set the gridview to display the names of the files present in the local folder of the app. the names are displayed in the "fileName" textblock.
Now i want to store the textblock(fileName) content into a variable, so that I can use the variable to access the files, when the user selects a particular item. How can i do this?

here are the xaml codes:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ImageOverlayAlbumDataTemplate">
        <Grid Background="#FF939598" Height="130" Width="130">
            <Image Source="/Assets/reel.png"  Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="#CC000000" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <TextBlock x:Name="fileName" Text="{Binding}" Margin="10,3,0,0" Width="120" Height="20" 
                   TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

<GridView x:Name="displayFiles" CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True" 
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageOverlayAlbumDataTemplate}" Margin="41,46,682,191" Grid.Row="1" >
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="3"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The gridview has a [selecteditems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.selecteditems.aspx) property on it that could be data bound to a list of strings.

Note you will also have to set the properties on the grid to allow multiple selections ([SelectionMode="multiple"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.selectionmode.aspx))